# Multimap of pointers as a class member on the heap

Tags: c++, class, pointers, heap-memory, multimap

[Edit:  I got some friends to look at this, and I'm fairly certain that how I handle some pointers within my member functions are the cause of this.  The problem is that all the new/heap/etc. tutorials and documentation I find online deal with super basic new and heap declarations within a 5-line main(), so I'm not sure how to address this.]

---

Okay, so originally the

```
std::multimap<Player*, Handle*>* heapTest;
```

was simply just a multimap class member, named such:

```
std::multimap<Player*, Handle*> playerHandleMap;
```

And here's a class function definition:

```
void DamageBox::OnEnter(Player& Player)  {
  Handle iterHolder = //Function that generates and returns a handle
  auto iteratorPlaceholder = playerHandleMap.emplace(&Player, &iterHolder);
}
```

Now if I now understand this correctly, this is yielding the memory garbaging, because iterHolder is declared within a class method, and so I smash that address within my playerHandleMap, and as soon as I leave the scope of the class instance, it becomes garbage.

What's the proper syntax here?

Is it, within the class method:

```
void DamageBox::OnEnter(Player& Player)  {
   Handle* iterHolder = new Handle(\\function that creates a handle)
      auto iteratorPlaceholder = playerHandleMap.emplace(&Player, iterHolder);
    }
```

But then where do my delete calls?  Would performing them as I do my playerHandleMap maintenance be sufficient, e.g. when i .erase a key-value pair, I first call delete on the Handle value?

---

#pragma once

```
#include "DetectionVolume.h"
#include "TimedCallback.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Clock.h"
#include <vector>

// Describes the information needed to create an FDamageVolume
struct DamageBoxSetup : public DetectionBoxSetup
{
public:
    DamageBoxSetup(const lotsOfArgsHere);

    const float DamagePerSec;
    const Clock::duration DamageInterval;
};

class DamageBox : public DetectionBox
{
public:
    DamageBox();
    DamageBox(const DamageBoxSetup& Setup);
    FDamageBox();

    // This shared instance is used in another method I'm not including here
    static DamageBox& shared_instance() {
        static DamageBox theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }

protected:

    float DamagePerSec;
    FClock::duration DamageInterval;
    double DamageDonePerInterval;

    std::multimap<Player*, Handle*>* heapTest;


    void QueueDamage(Player& Player, float damageQueued, Clock::duration& theInterval);

    virtual void OnEnter(Player& Player) override;
    virtual void OnExit(Player& Player) override;
};
```

So, I've been banging my head against the wall, because what was formerly `heapTest` here was just a regular multimap, not a pointer to one to be declared on the stack.  And in hours of debugging and tracking the values within, when the line stepper would leave the class methods, and then come back, a lot of the Handle pointers, the values in those pairs, had turned to garbage in the meantime.

1. Am I right in presuming that this is most likely a stack vs. heap problem and that I need to get this class member allocated onto the heap?

Naturally, I changed the multimap to a multimap*, added to my constructor the bottom line here

```
DamageBox::DamageBox(const DamageBoxSetup& Setup)
    : DetectionBox(Setup)
    , DamagePerSec(Setup.DamagePerSec)
    , DamageInterval(Setup.DamageInterval)
{
    auto timeInMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(DamageInterval).count();
    double IntervalTimeInS = static_cast<double>(timeInMs) / 1000.0;
    DamageDonePerInterval = DamagePerSec * IntervalTimeInS;

    heapTest = new std::multimap<FPlayer*, FTimedCallbackHandle*>;
}
```

and added a destructor:

```
DamageVolume::~DamageVolume() {
    delete heapTest;
}
```

, but after doing these two steps of what I thought was rigor, now I get exceptions/errors thrown when trying to do anything touching the `heapTest` multimap.

For example:

```
void DamageBox::OnEnter(Player& Player) {
  ///  Some stuff here
  Handle iterHolder = getTheHandle stuff;

  auto placeholder = heapTest->emplace(&Player,&iterHolder);
}
```

I get a freakout crash when it hits that emplace there.

In xtree:
`Exception thrown: read access violation. _Scary->**_Myhead** was nullptr. line 1572`

I'm not sure if it matters, but the instances of `DamageBox` used in the `main()` loop aren't on the heap - `heapTest` is the only thing I've tried declaring on the heap.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The original problem is that you're storing pointers to automatic objects, acquired with `&`, in your map. I suspect that you then broke your code further by not following "the rule of three" when you added the wrong solution. Stop thinking about "stack" or "heap" and start thinking about lifetime.

Comment: Consider to use smart pointers instead of raw ones. It will save you the need of manually managing the memory (and the bugs that come with it).

Comment: There seems to be no good reason for `heapTest` to be dynamically allocated. Just make it a class member. Note that "as a class member on the heap" makes little sense. Class members go wherever the class goes. For instance, if an object is global, all its members have static storage duration too. I suspect that a similar mental mistake is causing the problems with the `Handle*` in the map. That means the map does not contain Handles - it contains pointer to some random, uncontrolled location in memory, where a Handle lives - or in your example, where it used to live.

Comment: This question is soliciting mostly crystal ball gazing. It's quite far from a complete or minimal example. We have to take your word on far too much here, and in my experience, when people leave out information they think is unrelated, they often overlook the problem. For example, I see `DamageBox` has a default constructor, but you haven't shown it. How do we know you're initializing `heapTest` to NULL in there? And that's just the first thing I notice. Try removing absolutely ALL unrelated code and create a complete, minimal code example that can be compiled and run to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Not enough information to know, but this seems like a problem of too **many** pointers that would be solved by removing pointers not adding them. Or at least replacing raw pointers with smart pointers,

Comment: @MSalters but it is a class member - right?  I've declared it within the class definition of DamageBox, underneath protected:

Comment: A pointer to a standard container is more often than not a sign of deep confusion. Online tutorials are probably to blame.

Comment: @n.m. i would LOVE to be able to rectify my confusion - is there anything immediately actionable that you recommend?

Comment: Start by trying to convince your nearest rubber duck that `DamageBox` really needs a pointer-to-a-multimap member as a opposed to just a multimap member. If you think you have a compelling argument, try asking a question about it here. There is a good chance that it is wrong,

Comment: @DSiegmeyer: the **pointer** is a class member. But that pointer does not point to a class member.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use a pointer as the key of any type of map.    Instead, give a `Player` a unique (scalar) identity attribute and use that attribute as the key. You might need a `map<id_attribute, Player*>`  or some variant with a smart pointer to `Player`